# Grsecurity Policy Generation - role_allow_ip 127.0.0.6

Tags: grsecurity

the Grsecurity policy generation from a learning log file frequently yields role definitions with role attributes like

```
role_allow_ip 127.0.0.6
```

when in fact I have logged in via IPv6.  Since Grsecurity does not yet support IPv6 addressing - is this the way how a policy can express this?